# get() in Google Datastore doesn't work as intended

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building a basic blog from the Web Development course by Steve Hoffman on Udacity. This is my code -

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)

def datetimeformat(value, format='%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y'):
    return value.strftime(format)

jinja_env.filters['datetimeformat'] = datetimeformat

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class Entries(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    body = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        entries = db.GqlQuery('select * from Entries order by created desc limit 10')
        self.response.write(render_str('mainpage.html', entries=entries))

class NewPost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(render_str('newpost.html', error=""))

    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get('title')
        body = self.request.get('body')

        if title and body:
            e = Entries(title=title, body=body)
            length = db.GqlQuery('select * from Entries order by created desc').count()
            e.put()
            self.redirect('/newpost/' + str(length+1))
        else:
            self.response.write(render_str('newpost.html', error="Please type in a title and some content"))

class Permalink(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        e = db.GqlQuery('select * from Entries order by created desc').get()
        self.response.write(render_str('permalink.html', id=id, entry = e))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                            ('/newpost', NewPost),
                            ('/newpost/(\d+)', Permalink)
                            ], debug=True)
```

In the class `Permalink`, I'm using the `get()` method on the query than returns all records in the descending order of creation. So, it should return the most recently added record. But when I try to add a new record, `permalink.html` (it's just a page with shows the title, the body and the date of creation of the new entry) shows the SECOND most recently added. For example, I already had three records, so when I added a fourth record, instead of showing the details of the fourth record, `permalink.html` showed me the details of the third record. Am I doing something wrong?

I don't think my question is a duplicate of this - [Read delay in App Engine Datastore after put()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063597/read-delay-in-app-engine-datastore-after-put). That question is about read delay of `put()`, while I'm using `get()`. The accepted answer also states that `get()` doesn't cause any delay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read delay in App Engine Datastore after put()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063597/read-delay-in-app-engine-datastore-after-put)

Comment: No I don't think it is. The answer states `get()` doesn't cause any read delay.

Comment: it's not really a delay, it's an eventual consistency issue. There's a gazillion not-exactly-matching questions with answers that all boil down to "read about eventual consistency" :)

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. I will. :)

Comment: Eventual consistency aside, why does your `Permalink.get` accept the `id` of the post yet you ignore it and query for the most recent instead? A get by id avoids the eventual consistency issue.

Comment: Yes, I know that now after reading docs provided in the answer. I was using the id only to set up a permalink page as described in the course. I know now I can use it to set up ancestor queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of eventual consistency used by default for GQL queries.

You need to read:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/data-consistency
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency
- https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/
- search & read on SO and other source about strong & eventual consistency in Google Cloud Datastore.

You can specify [`read_policy=STRONG_CONSISTENCY`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/data-consistency) for your query but it has associated costs that you should be aware of and take into account.

Comment: I just got a NameError by including that. `global name 'STRONG_CONSISTENCY' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I had to add `db.STRONG_CONSISTENCY`. Sorry again for sending you a notification.